# Catching checkbox changes inside bootrstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I need to catch chekcbox changes inside partial view rendered as bootstrap modal dialog. I tried using

```
$(".modal input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $(".modal input:checkbox").attr("checked", false);
    $(this).attr("checked", true);
});
```

with no luck.

this is view:

```
@model List<MyModel>

<div class="modal-header">
    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSomething", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table borderless">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(item => item[i].Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item[i].Checked)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item[i].Title, new { @style = "border: none; width: 100% " })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item[i].Desc, new { @style = "border: none; width: 100% " })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Close</button>
    </div>
}
```

dialog is called with actionlink from main view.

Comment: Is the modal rendered using ajax? Where is the javascript loaded?

Comment: Since it is a partial view I think you need **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here.. So Try `$('document').on('change',".modal input:checkbox",function () {`...

Comment: I do not know what bootstrap uses behind i call js inside registered *.js and function call  is $(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function() {
        $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});

Comment: @GuruprasadRao tried, its not working